Deprecation error in node.js with message future versions of node.js will throw an error
I'm encountering a deprecation error in my Node.js application. I'm using npm install command to install the inquirer package. It shows the following error message:

Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.

I'm not sure how to resolve it.I tried to solve this error but nothing works. Could anyone help me?
I reinstall Node.js, cleared the cached data and tried to solve it up.

"will throw an error" - means it's not an error now. It's a warning. You probably can't or doesn't have to do anything with it, but it's unknown if it's so, this depends on your case. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There could be 2 reasons for this warning:
1 - Your Node.js is not updated on the last stable version

If this is your situation just install the LTS version of Node
Update all you packages again with npm update
And check again if the versions are correct
node -v
npm -v

2 - The package you are trying to install is using a deprecated method or API
Your package is probably using deprecated API's, so the only think you could do in this case is try to find another package that does the same think, or go on the package open source and try to solve it yourself, helping the project.
Or just use the package you're using, but in some time it will probably be malfunctioning if the developers doesn't update it
